# Writing Mass Balance Equations

Tags: acid-base, notation

I was curious if there is a specific reason why when writing mass balance reactions we always leave a $\ce{H+}$ on the left side of the equation as the professor did not explain so, or is it just convention?

For example, write the mass balance equation of $\ce{H3PO4}$:

$$\ce{H2O <=> H+ +OH-}$$
$$\ce{H3PO4 <=> H+ +H_2PO4^{-}(aq)}$$
$$\ce{H2PO4- <=>H+ + HPO4^{2-}(aq)}$$
$$\ce{HPO4^2- <=> H+ + PO4^{3-}(aq)}$$

Comment: What do you mean by 'we always leave a $H^+$ on the left side of the equation'

Comment: It does not have to be done that way but that is how most people show it.

Comment: Those are not mass balance equations. The mass balance equation is $[\ce{H3PO4}] + [\ce{H2PO3-}] + [\ce{HPO4^2-}] + [\ce{PO4^3-}] = c_{\ce{H3PO4}}$.

Comment: I apologize I miserably attempted to write them in latex it did not work.  I think I still do not understand the general concept of mass balance, so it is something beyond what I would ask here.

Comment: Do you mean why the proton is "always" written as the first product? I am not aware of such a convention. As long as all products are there with the correct stoichiometric coefficient, it does not matter if the proton is written first, last, or somewhere in-between.

Comment: Well, I guess you can call these "dissociations of $\ce{H3PO4}$". Anyway, as Anders and Frisbee have said, there's absolutely no requirement that the proton be the first product.

Comment: When writing **charge balance** reactions we always leave an **[$\ce{H+}$]** on the left side of the equation as
$$[\ce{H+}] 
    = 3[\ce{PO4^3-}] + 2[\ce{HPO4^2-}] + [\ce{HPO4-}] + [\ce{OH-}] $$

Answer (score 1):

There is no such convention explicitly telling what comes out first.
Here, for a *traditional formula* of phosphoric(V) acid $\ce{H3PO4}$ writing a proton first serves only a *didactic purpose*.
It's visually easier for students to keep a track on dissociation as the order of the elements both in formula and among the products is preserved.

On the other hand, shall one use a *coordination formula* of phosphoric(V) acid $\ce{[PO(OH)3]}$, it probably would make more sense to use a reversed order and put $\ce{H+}$ at the end:

$$
\begin{align}
\ce{[PO(OH)3] &<=> [PO2(OH)2]- + H+}\\
\ce{[PO2(OH)2]- &<=> [PO3(OH)]^2- + H+}\\
\ce{[PO3(OH)]^2- &<=> [PO4]^{3-} + H+}
\end{align}
$$

One more minor thing.
Equations are usually aligned about arrows, and a tabular array of products and reactants emerges when the same repeating compound ($\ce{H+}$) is shown first.
Note how easier it is to grasp the information when more compounds are aligned:

$$
\begin{align}
&\color{green}{\text{aligned}} & &\color{red}{\text{misaligned}}\\
\ce{H3PO4 &<=> H+ + H_2PO4^{-}(aq)} &\quad \ce{H3PO4 &<=> H_2PO4^{-}(aq) + H+} \\
\ce{H2PO4- &<=>H+ + HPO4^{2-}(aq)} &\quad \ce{H2PO4- &<=> HPO4^{2-}(aq) + H+} \\
\ce{HPO4^2- &<=> H+ + PO4^{3-}(aq)} &\quad \ce{HPO4^2- &<=> PO4^{3-}(aq) + H+}
\end{align}
$$